# Mac OSX capture all keypresses from MenuBar application

Tags: macos, keydown

I'm sure most people are familiar with Alfred, the awesome task launcher. What I want to know is how does Alfred detect that I'm pressing Command-Shift-Space to launch its UI? Does it override `keyDown' or something entirely different?

Every post I've seen so far talks about overriding `keyDown` but from my understanding, that override has to be part of a view. How does Alfred do it without having a view being presented, with just the menubar icon on top?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to monitor global keypresses.

> You can also create a global event monitor that allows you to monitor events in other applications, although you are unable to alter those events.

Specifically, look at `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`, which installs an event monitor that receives copies of events posted to other applications.

```
+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(void (^)(NSEvent*))block
```

> Events are delivered asynchronously to your app and you can only observe the event; you cannot modify or otherwise prevent the event from being delivered to its original target application.
>
> Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility is enabled or if your application is trusted for accessibility access (see AXIsProcessTrusted).

If you do want to prevent or modify the events, you should instead look into [CGEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Alfred requires that it be trusted for accessibility access or if you're willing to require that your own app is.

Either way, rather than using either `-[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:...]` or event taps, you can use the old Carbon hot-key API. It is still not deprecated, even though most of the rest of Carbon is.  See [RegisterEventHotKey()](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Carbon_Event_Manager_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/RegisterEventHotKey).